# Using a variable in awk command to name file

Tags: shell, awk, ksh

I am splitting up a file with awk command, I want to name the file using a variable however I have not had much luck.  Here is the line:

```
awk '/STX/ {f="$tp"++i;} {print > f}' $tp.mixed
```

this just creates files with $tp# as name.

I read the post "How to use shell variables in awk script" but was unable to figure out how to apply that to me question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use shell variables in awk script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script)

Comment: I saw this before I posted, could not figure out to apply it to my particular question.  Thank you

Comment: You don't expand the shell variable **in** the awk script. You use `-v awkvar="$tp"`` to create an awk variable with the value you need and then use the variable `awkvar` in the awk script. `f=awkvar(++i)` or similar.

Comment: so like this: awk -v awkvar="$tp" '/STX/ {f=awkvar(++i);} {print > f}' $tp.mixed

Comment: I have: awk -v tp=$tp '/STX/ {f=tp++i;} {print > f}' $tp.mixed and I get 0,1,2,3,4,etc, if I use tp(++1) I receive error, function tp not defined.

Comment: `awk -v tp="$tp" '/STX/ {if (f) close(f); f = tp (++i)} {print > f} END{if (f) close(f)}' $tp.mixed`

Comment: Thank you anubhava!!  that worked.  Question, why do you have to have the if (f) close (f) and END{if (f) close(f)?  thank you, trying to understand shell scripting and awk better.

Comment: @BrianDuffy There is a limit on the number of open files you can have.  If   you explicitly use `close` every time you are done with a file here, you will never reach that limit.

Comment: thank you for explanation @John1024, anabhava, can you add as an answer so I can mark this solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk command to pass variable from command line:

```
awk -v tp="$tp" '/STX/{close(f); f=tp (++i)} f{print > f} END{close(f)}' "$tp.mixed"
```

Also important is to close the files you're opening for writing output. By calling `close` we are avoiding memory leak due to large number of opened files.

Answer (score 0):

anubhava answered my question in the comments:

```
awk -v tp="$tp" '/STX/ {if (f) close(f); f = tp (++i)} {print > f} END{if (f) close(f)}' $tp.mixed
```

works

thank you everyone for your help